# How to redirect to login in FastApi

Tags: python, fastapi

I am looking to get a simple login sequence on fastapi:
following [This tutorial](https://slatebit.com/fastapi/google/oauth/2020/08/16/fastapi_google_oauth_part1.html)

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, HTTPException
from starlette.config import Config
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse, RedirectResponse
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth, OAuthError

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="!secret")

config = Config(".env")
oauth = OAuth(config)

CONF_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"
oauth.register(
    name="google",
    server_metadata_url=CONF_URL,
    client_kwargs={"scope": "openid email profile"},
)

@app.get("/")
async def home(request: Request):
    user = request.session.get("user")
    if user is not None:
        email = user["email"]
        html = (
            f"<pre>Email: {email}</pre><br>"
            '<a href="/docs">documentation</a><br>'
            '<a href="/logout">logout</a>'
        )
        return HTMLResponse(html)
    return HTMLResponse('<a href="/login">login</a>')

@app.get("/login", tags=["authentication"])
async def login(request: Request):
    redirect_uri = request.url_for("auth")
    return await oauth.google.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)


@app.get("/auth")
async def auth(request: Request):
    try:
        token = await oauth.google.authorize_access_token(request)
    except OAuthError as error:
        return HTMLResponse(f"<h1>{error.error}</h1>")
    user = token.get("userinfo")
    if user:
        request.session["user"] = dict(user)
    return RedirectResponse(url="/")

@app.get("/logout", tags=["authentication"])
async def logout(request: Request):
    request.session.pop("user", None)
    return RedirectResponse(url="/")


# Try to get the logged in user
async def get_user(request: Request) -> Optional[dict]:
    user = request.session.get("user")
    if user is not None:
        return user
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Could not validate credentials.")
    return None

# Endpoint to protect
@app.get("/other_endpoint/")
async def other_endpoint_function(
    user: Optional[dict] = Depends(get_user), id: str
):
    # Chek if other is authenticated
    if user.is_authenticated:
        function()
    else:
        # First redirect to the login page
        RedirectResponse("login")
        # Once logged in re-run the initial request
        RedirectResponse(f"/other_endpoint/{id}")
```

I am looking to protect only the **other_endpoint** the homepage has a link to the login page.

- **check that the user is authenticated** before running the **function**

  - If the user is **authenticated**, run **function**
  - If the user is **not authenticated**

    1. **redirect to the login page**
    2. **re-run the function** after authentication

So far, I have tried multiple implementations with **RedirectResponse**, but i ends up bypassing the authentication

Comment: You don't have any reference to `get_user` in your `async def home(request: Request):` definition: is this the one you're trying to protect? You can't have multiple RedirectReponses in `other_endpoint_function` either, and since you don't return either - neither will have any effect.

Comment: @MatsLindh Good catch, I am only looking to protect the other_endpoint, the home does not need to be protected, and I understant I can't have multiple RedirectReponses, but I am not sure how to get the desired effect

Comment: First - you'll never get a RedirectResponse as long as your user handler raises an 403 exception. However, you can add an exception handler: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/ - and return a RedirectResponse to the login endpoint when a "LoginRequired" or similar named exception (you'll create this exception yourself) gets raised; you can attach the URL used in this exception (based on `request.url` for example, iirc) and use it as a "next" parameter in the returned redirect response, allowing you to redirect the user to the actual endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but has been viewed so many times that it deserves a proper answer. The first thing you do is create an exception.

```py
class RequiresLogin(Exception):
    pass
```

Next you install [a handler for this exception](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#install-custom-exception-handlers) in FastAPI like so

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from urllib.parse import quote

app = FastAPI()

@app.exception_handler(RequiresLogin)
async def requires_login(request: Request, _: Exception):
    return RedirectResponse(f"/login?next={quote(request.url._url)}")
```

Notice the `?next=` parameter. You can handle this however you like but this is simple and works. The `Request` object comes from [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/requests/) and while it's undocumented the [`_url` parameter of the `URL` object](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/a8b8856ce393a82ab4a714131085dbc4d658e34d/starlette/datastructures.py#L60) gives you the full URL string. Next figure out how to determine if the user is authed. This is going to be application specific so it's represented as the `get_current_user` function. From there create a [dependable](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#create-a-dependency-or-dependable) (i.e. just a function) that fetches the current user.

```
async def current_user(request: Request):
    current_user = get_current_user(request.cookies.get("auth"))
    if not current_user:
        raise RequiresLogin("You must be logged in to access this")

    return current_user
```

Then create your login route. Again this will be application specific but here's what my OAuth login route looks like.

```py
@app.get("/login")
async def login(request: Request, next: Optional[str] = None):
    return templates.TemplateResponse(
        "login.html",
        {
            "request": request,
            "authorize_url": client.get_authorize_url(
                redirect_uri=f"{ApiHost.get()}/oauth-hook",
                state=generate_message(json.dumps({"next": next}, separators=(",", ":"))),
            ),
        },
    )

@app.get("/oauth-hook", response_class=RedirectResponse)
async def oauth_hook(response: Response, code: str, state: Optional[str] = None):
    # Your app specific OAuth logic
    # ...

    if state:
        try:
            decoded = json.loads(decode_message(state))
        except InvalidSignature:
            return "/some/default/page"

        if next := decoded.get("next"):
            return next
```

Since OAuth is popular one slight tangent, I'm passing the next URL in the OAuth state parameter that gets posted back to my server once the user signs in. Nothing is stopping someone from modifying this in flight so `generate_mesasge` and `decode_message` uses [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) and [`hmac`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html) to validate that I get exactly the state I sent.

Finally, here's the secret sauce. To add authentication to an arbitrary route do something like this.

```py
@app.get("/my/route")
async def my_route(user = Depends(current_user)):
   # Whatever it is your route does.
   pass
```

If the user isn't authenticated the `RequiresLogin` exception will be thrown, it will be caught by the handler, and the route will return the appropriate `RedirectResponse` -- otherwise the route will be ran as normal.

@Benjamin, I know this answer retreads over stuff you already know but when I first stumbled across this question I didn't know about FastAPI's dependency injection so I assume other people won't either.